# Solving a MILP instead of a MIQP that has diagonal 1 in quadratic matrix

Tags: linear-programming, quadratic-programming, mixed-integer-programming

This problem is a Mixed Integer Quadratic Program that has a diagonal quadratic matrix of 1s.
$$
\max_{x\text{ s.t. }Ax\leq b}\left\{ \ a'x-\frac{1}{2}x'  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \dots &0 \\
    0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 &\dots & 1
  \end{bmatrix}x\right\}
$$
with the additional condition that $x_i\in\{0,\ 1\}$ for some $i$s.

**Question**: is there a way to rewrite this problem (or at least approximate its solution) as a Mixed Integer Linear Program?

Comment: You cannot linearize it exactly, but why would you want to approximate it? Modern solvers should handle it (linear constraints, concave objective).

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is to maximize $$\sum_i a_i x_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_i x_i^2.$$  If $x_i\in\{0,1\}$, you can replace $x_i^2$ with $x_i$. For the other $x_i$, you have $x_i^2 \ge 0$, so replacing the objective function with the linear function $$\sum_{i\in N} a_i x_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in I} x_i,$$ where $I \subseteq N$ is the index set for the binary variables, yields an upper bound on the original objective because
$$
\sum_{i\in N} a_i x_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in I} x_i
=\sum_{i\in N} a_i x_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in I} x_i^2
\ge \sum_{i\in N} a_i x_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \in N} x_i^2
$$